# Good Oracle book for MySQL users?

Tags: mysql, oracle

Just started using Oracle, no previous experience. I do have a good amount of experience with MySQL (and played a little with PostgreSQL). Could you recommend me a good introductory book to Oracle that takes into account the fact that I do have experience with these other DBs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that Tom Kyte says.  He's written a few books for different purposes, so you'll want to pick the book specific to your concern.  He's the most informative and helpful author I know of for Oracle.

For a stackoverflow-like experience with Oracle, you can also go to [http://asktom.oracle.com](http://asktom.oracle.com/).

Comment: Just to support this, his books cover the Oracle architecture which will explain why it is best to do things in a particular way with Oracle. Also, he has done a lot of the work in the new 11gR2 concepts manual http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/toc.htm which would be a good (free) starting point.